# download file using php, file is stored in a folder and name of the file is stored in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to download a file from mysqli database using php for that i have   stored file in a folder and file name is stored in the mysqli database.

here is my code...

```
 $query= mysqli_query($dbo,"SELECT * FROM diff_questions WHERE email = ' $email ' and status= '0' ");
$rows=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
$file=$rows['file'];
$path='http://localhost/admin1/uploads';
?>

echo "<a href='download.php?file=".$file."&path=".$path." '>Download File</a> ";
```

and now 
download.php-

```
<?php
$file = $_GET["file"];
$path = $_GET["path"];
$fullfile = $path.$file;
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . Urlencode($file));   
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
header("Content-Length: " . Filesize($fullfile));
flush();
$fp = fopen($fullfile, "r");
while (!feof($fp))
{
    echo fread($fp, 65536);
    flush();
} 
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with code. Its not working . 
i mean it working file till saving file but its not downloading full file imean afther downloading file size of file is 0kb

Comment: what is happening - or not happening?

Comment: Could you give sample file name? Just want to make sure you have correct full file path after the concatenantion $path.$file

Comment: Your code is working fine . Please check your file type you are downloading

Comment: I think you should remove the spaces around the `$email` variable in the sql

Comment: @ravi it is downloading file with 0kb size and i have tried different type of file to download

Comment: @ramraider  i think in  this there is not a problem of sql

Comment: ok - but it changes the results surely that the sql will return as you explicitly ask to find the email with leading and trailing spaces

Comment: @ramraider yeah thanks for advice

Comment: Thanks buddy it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once replace your download.php with following code and check if its working for you or not :

```
if(isset($_GET["file"])){
      $file = $_GET["file"];
      $path = $_GET["path"];
      $fullfile = $path.$file;

      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . Urlencode($file));   
      header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
      header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
      header("Content-Type: application/download");
      header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
      $fp = fopen($fullfile,'r');
        while ($line = fgets($fp)) {
        echo($line);
      }
      fclose($fp);
    }
```

Comment: if works than upvote this post. so that it will help others.